# Does the ostream class have an operator<<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently trying to learn operator overloading and have a small example that I am trying to understand.

```
#pragma once

class Vector2
{
    public:
        int u, v;

    Vector2(int u, int v): u(u), v(v){ };
};
```

and

```
#include "Vector2.h"

#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector2& other) {
    stream << other.u << ", " << other.v;
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Vector2(10, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

My first question here is, when utilizing `operator<<` this is a global function that we are defining to be called when given the two parameter types, in this example `std::ostream` and `Vector2` so I can interpret this as, "When given a `std::ostream` on the left of `<<` and `Vector2` on the right, call this function". However, this does not itself print to standard output. When given the objects, we still need to call `stream << other.u`. This means that the `ostream` class should have a `operator<<` somewhere. However in my IDE, I try to follow on find the definition, however I am taken to a, `using ostream = basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>;`. At my current C++ level, I do not know where to follow this, but my instinct is that somewhere there should be a class called `ostream` that has `operator<<` implemented, is this correct?

Comment: It's actually another [free function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), but yes, there are built-in functions that take an `ostream&` on the left hand side and a fundamental type on the right and do the printing.

Comment: I don't follow what the actual question is. Are you trying to understand how the overall operator overloading system works? Are you looking for documentation on what `operator<<` will do for various types (like `int`)? Are you hoping to find actual C++ code in an actual library file that implements the `operator<<` overload? (If so, what *problem do you hope to solve* by looking at that code?) Something else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was a bit confused seeing operator overloading for functions, given that they're outside of the class. When inside, it makes sense to me, however seeing a function be responsible for operator overloading is a bit funny. However from what I can tell is that "operator<<" when used as a function does not actually do anything but gather the objects, you still, in this example need to implement "operator<<" on the class, I was trying to understand it because we still utilize "stream << other.u" in this example so I thought it must be on the class. I did not want to understand how t

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the implementation is done exactly on ostream, I just wanted to make sure my understanding of operator overloading was correct, that operator<< as a function gathers the two objects, whereas "stream << other.u" utilizes operator<< on the ostream class still.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is creating "std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector2& other)" effectively the same as adding a `operator<<(Vector2 &other)` to the "ostream" class, but being done outside?

Comment: It depends on what you consider "effectively the same" or not. Either way would implement the operator, yes. You do it this way because the `ostream` class already exists and you don't get to modify it.

Comment: `std::ostream` is actually a synonym for `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >` i.e. it is a specialisation of a templated class named `std::basic_ostream`.   The templated `basic_osteam` class does have a number of overloads of member functions named `operator<<()`.       It doesn't supply such member functions for user-defined classes, and modifying classes in namespace `std` is not allowed, which is why you supply free functions named `operator<<()` that accept two arguments to provide streaming capability for your class.

Comment: You may need to apeend `\n` or `std::endl` to see the output

Comment: Overloaded binary operator calls are looked up as member functions of the first operand, and also as free functions on both operands

Comment: @M.M Cheers, simplistic sentence.